# Error extracting images in powerpoint using shape.export and identifying paragraph format as bullets in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I repurposed the code on [MicrosoftPowerpointConverter - MoinMoin](https://moinmo.in/MicrosoftPowerpointConverter) to work without the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

I was able to generate a new file and export text to it, (I know that's the easy part), where I am getting stuck is in two places:

1. Formatting bullets:

   - Original code

     ```
     ' Check for bullets
     If aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoTrue Then
         outText = Replace(outText, Chr(10), " * ")
     End If
     ```
   - My  code

     ```
     ' Check for bullets
     If oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type <> ppBulletNone Then
          outText = Replace(outText, Chr(10), " * ")
     End If
     ```

> This doesn't work at all, and it totally ignores bullet formatting, but still outputs the content without the *

2. Exporting images:

   - Original Code

     ```
     ' Is it a picture or embedded object
     If aShape.Type = msoPicture Or aShape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Or aShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or aShape.Type = msoGroup Then
         aShape.Export outPath + "\image" + Trim(Str(i)) + Trim(Str(j)) + ".png", ppShapeFormatPNG
         oFileStream.WriteLine (Chr(13) + "attachment:image" + Trim(Str(i)) + Trim(Str(j)) + ".png" + Chr(13))
     End If
     ```
   - My code

     ```
     ' Is it a picture or embedded object
     If oShape.Type = msoPicture Or oShape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Or oShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or oShape.Type = msoGroup Then
         Dim imagepath
         imagepath = oPres.Path & "/images/slide" + Trim(Str(i)) + Trim(Str(j)) + ".png"
         oShape.Export imagepath, ppShapeFormatPNG
         Print #iFile, (Chr(13) + "<img src=" + Chr(34) + "/images/slide" + Trim(Str(i)) + Trim(Str(j)) + ".png" + Chr(34) + ">" + Chr(13))
     End If
     ```

> This code throws up the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEdOU.png) in windows, and is totally ignored in Mac

Adding my complete code below:

```
Sub ExportToWiki()



' Iterators
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

' Pres, Slide, Shape
Dim oPres As Presentation
Dim oSlides As Slides
Dim oSlide As Slide         'Slide Object
Dim oShp As Shape         'Shape Object
Dim iFile As Integer      'File handle for output
iFile = FreeFile          'Get a free file number
Dim PathSep As String
Dim FileNum As Integer


Set oPres = ActivePresentation
Set oSlides = oPres.Slides

FileNum = FreeFile

'Open output file
' NOTE:  errors here if file hasn't been saved
Open oPres.Path & "/text.xml" For Output As FileNum

' File Handling
Dim outText As String

' Table exports
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim cellText As String


' Select my ppt

' Write TOC
Print #iFile, ("[[TableOfContents]]")

' Loop through slides
For i = 1 To oPres.Slides.Count

    Set oSlide = oPres.Slides(i)

    ' Loop through shapes
    For j = 1 To oSlide.Shapes.Count

        Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes(j)

        ' Is it a text frame?
        If oShape.HasTextFrame Then

            If oShape.TextFrame.HasText Then

                outText = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

                ' Check for bullets
                If oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type <> ppBulletNone Then
                    outText = Replace(outText, Chr(10), " * ")
                End If

                If j = 1 Then ' Assume first text is always the header
                    outText = "= " + outText + " ="
                 End If

                 Print #iFile, (outText + Chr(13) + "[[BR]]" + Chr(13))

            End If

        End If

        ' Is it a table?
        If oShape.Type = msoTable Then

            cellText = ""

            For row = 1 To oShape.Table.Rows.Count
                For col = 1 To oShape.Table.Columns.Count

                    If row = 1 Then
                        cellText = cellText + "||<class=" + Chr(34) + "tableheader" + Chr(34) + ">" + oShape.Table.Columns.Item(col).Cells(row).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                    Else
                        cellText = cellText + "||" + oShape.Table.Columns.Item(col).Cells(row).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                    End If

                    If col = oShape.Table.Columns.Count Then
                        cellText = cellText + "||" + Chr(13)
                    End If

                Next col
            Next row

            Print #iFile, (Chr(13) + cellText + Chr(13))

        End If

        ' Is it a picture or embedded object
        If oShape.Type = msoPicture Or oShape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Or oShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or oShape.Type = msoGroup Then
            Dim imagepath
            imagepath = oPres.Path & "/images/slide" + Trim(Str(i)) + Trim(Str(j)) + ".png"
            oShape.Export imagepath, ppShapeFormatPNG
            Print #iFile, (Chr(13) + "<img src=" + Chr(34) + "/images/slide" + Trim(Str(i)) + Trim(Str(j)) + ".png" + Chr(34) + ">" + Chr(13))
        End If

    Next j
Next i

Close #iFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, I think you probably need to recursively check each paragraph within the TextRange as bullets can be set for the whole text range or specific paragraphs within it and if there is a mix, you'll get unexpected results. I also don't see why the replacement is being made for Char 10. I think you should be returning the text for the paragraphs where a bullet is found and prefixing it with your Wiki string. For example:

```
' Check for bullets
Dim p As Long
Dim para As String
With oShape.TextFrame.TextRange
  For p = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
    If .Paragraphs(p).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type <> ppBulletNone Then
      para = " * " & .Paragraphs(p).Text
    Else
      para = .Paragraphs(p).Text
    End If
    outText = outText & para
  Next
End With
```

For the second point, I got the same error because the images sub folder didn't exist. Once I created it manually, the code ran on PC. For Mac, you'll need to use POSIX or AppleScript path syntax if I recall correctly, for example:

```
#If Mac Then
  Public Const PathSeparator = ":"
#Else
  Public Const PathSeparator = "\"
#End If
```

However, if you're using PowerPoint:mac 2016 then things are more complicated due to its sandboxed environment. Check this article for more info:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm

Comment: Glad it worked for you Harkirat. If you can, please up vote the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I did upvote, but apparently i am not reputable enough for it to show